# How many homomorphisms are there from $\mathbb D_5$ to $\mathbb A_4$?

Tags: group-theory, permutations, group-homomorphism

> How many homomorphisms are there from $\mathbb D_5$ to $\mathbb A_4$? Find one of them which is nottrivial.

**My try:**

To be honest, I don't really understand how to find homomorphisms between groups, so I will present what I was able to deduce:

$$\mathbb D_5 = <\rho,\epsilon: \rho^5=1,\epsilon^2=1, \epsilon\rho\epsilon=\rho^{-1}>=$$ $$=<1,\rho,\rho^2,\rho^3,\rho^4,\epsilon,\epsilon\rho,\epsilon\rho^2,\epsilon\rho^3,\epsilon\rho^4> $$
$$\mathbb A_4=\left\{\text{id},(12)(34),(13)(24),(14)(23)\right\}$$

$\mathbb D_5$ is generated by $\rho$ and $\epsilon$. Let $f:\mathbb D_5 \rightarrow \mathbb A_4$ so we have:
$$\text{ord}(\rho)=5 \Rightarrow \text{ord}(f(\rho))=1 \text{ or } \text{ord}(f(\rho))=5$$
$$\text{ord}(\epsilon)=2 \Rightarrow \text{ord}(f(\epsilon))=1 \text{ or } \text{ord}(f(\epsilon))=2$$
Then we have:
$$\text{ord}(\text{id})=1$$ $$\text{ord}((12)(34))=\text{ord}((13)(24))=\text{ord}((14)(23))=2$$
That's why we must have:
$$f(\rho)=\text{id}$$ and $\epsilon$ can go to any item from $\mathbb A_4$. So exists $4$ homomorphisms from $\mathbb D_5$ to $\mathbb A_4$.

It is correct solution?

If so, how can I determine specific homomorphism now?

Comment: Do you know anything about presentations of groups by generators and relations ? you seem to do so, but I want to be sure.

Comment: By $A_4$ you seem to mean $\mathbb Z_2^2=V$. $|A_4|=4!/2=12$ but your "$A_4$" has order $4$.

Comment: @KemonoChen $\mathbb A_4$ is a group of even permutations from $S_4$ where $S_4$ is the permutation of four elements

Comment: @GreginGre from my knowledge homomorphism is clearly defined by what elements the generators of a given group go to

Comment: You miss a lot of elements. What about 3-cycles?

Comment: @GreginGre oh, you have right... $3$-cycles and $4$-cycles has $0$ translations so also are even

Comment: Sorry, it was a misprint. 4-cycles are not even, but 3-cycles indeed are.

I rephrase my previous question: do you know what a presentation of a group is (in terms of quotient group of a free group) and its basic properties ?

Comment: @GreginGre Why " 4-cycles are not even, but 3-cycles indeed are" if in both cases we have 0 translations?  Answering your question: as I wrote above "homomorphism is clearly defined by what elements the generators of a given group go to". Moreover I know that we can use normal supgroup to find homomorphism (but I don't understand how to do it) and quotient group is a set of layers of a given group relative to a certain normal subgroup. But maybe you are talking about something else, because I realize that I do not quite understand the search for homomorphisms, so I asked for help in this post

Comment: the signature of a $k$-cycle is $(-1)^{k-1}$...

Comment: Asuming you show that the elements of order 1,2 in $\mathbb{A}_4$ are indeed what you listed, this proof is correct. And they are indeed.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your $A_4$ misses a lot of elements. You miss the $3$-cycles.

Let be a morphism $f:D_5\to A_4$. Let $a=f(\rho)$, $b=f(\epsilon)$. Then $a^5=Id,b^2=Id$ and $bab^{-1}=a^{-1}$ since a morphism preserves products and inverses.

There is no element of order $5$ in $A_4$, so $a=1$. The elements of order $1$ or $2$ is $A_4$ are $Id$ and the product of two transpositions with disjoint supports, so $b$ is one of these $4$ elements. The relation $bab^{-1}=a^{-1}$ is trivially satisfied since $a=Id$.

So there is **at most** $4$ morphisms.You need to show that , conversely, if $b$ has order $1$ or $2$ in $A_4$, there exists a unique morphism $f:D_5\to A_4$ such that $f(\rho)=1$ and $f(\epsilon)=b$.

You have two possibilities , depending on your knowledge on group presentations.

**First proof.**  $D_5 = <\rho,\epsilon: \rho^5=1,\epsilon^2=1, \epsilon\rho\epsilon=\rho^{-1}>=F/R$, where $F$ is the free group on two letters $\{\rho,\epsilon\}$ and $R$ is the normal subgroup generated by $\rho^5,\epsilon^2, \epsilon\rho\epsilon\rho.$ 
The general theory says that morphisms that morphisms $D_5=F/R\to A_4$ are exactly "evaluation morphisms", where the images $a$ and $b$ of $\rho $ and $\epsilon$ satisfy the imposed relations $R$, that is $a^5=Id,b^2=Id$ and $bab^{-1}=a^{-1}$. So we are done here.

[More precisely: The factorisation theorem tells you that morphisms $F/R\to A_4$ comes from a unique morphism $F\to A_4$ which contains $R$ in its kernel.

Since $F$ is free, morphisms $F\to R$ are exactly "evaluation morphisms", and are uniquely determined by the images $a$ and $b$  of $\rho $  and $\epsilon$ respectively. Saying that the corresponding morphism contains $R$ in it kernel is equivalent to ask  $a^5=Id,b^2=Id$ and $bab^{-1}=a^{-1}$, and we are done.]

**Second proof.** From scratch. First, you need to convince yourself that an element of $D_5$ can we written **in a unique way** as $\rho^m \epsilon^n, 0\leq m\leq 4,n=0,1$. I let you do it.

In particular, if $f:D_5\to A_4$ is a morphism, we have 
$$f((\rho^m\epsilon^n))=f(\rho)^m f(\epsilon)^n=b^n.$$ What remains to do is that the map $f_b: D_5\to A_4$
 defined by  $$f_b(\rho^m\epsilon^n)=b^n, 0\leq m\leq 4,n=0,1$$  is indeed a morphism.

The key observation now is that for all $r\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $s\in\mathbb{Z}$ we have $f_b(\rho^r \epsilon^s)=b^s$. Notice that there is something to prove since a priori we only know what happens for $0\leq r \leq 4$ and $s=0,1$.

To do so, write $r=4q+m, 0\leq m\leq 4$ and $s=2q'+n, n=0,1$, and use the fact that $b^2=1$.

Now we can prove that $f_b$ is a morphism .We have $(\rho^m\epsilon^n)(\rho^k\epsilon^\ell)=\rho^{m+(-1)^nk}\epsilon^{n+\ell}$, so 
$$f_b((\rho^m\epsilon^n)(\rho^k\epsilon^\ell))=f_b(\rho^{m+(-1)^nk}\epsilon^{n+\ell})=b^{n+\ell}=b^n b^\ell=f_b(\rho^m\epsilon^n)f_b(\rho^k\epsilon^\ell)).$$

Note that we used the key obervation, since the integers $m+(-1)^nk$ and $n+\ell$ may live outside $\{0,\ldots,4\}$ and $\{0,1\}$ respectively.

All in all , the morphisms you seek are exactly the maps $f_b:D_5\to A_4$, where $b=Id, (1 2)(34), (13)(24), (14)(23)$

Comment: Thank you very much, amazingly educational solution!
However, I have two questions for you: 1) In the comments you didn't answer me why 3-cycles are even but 4-cycles not even? 2) Are you sure that $a^5=Id,b^2=Id,bab^{-1}=a^{-1}$ not $\rho^5=Id,\epsilon^2=Id$?

Comment: 1) Already answered that: the signature of a $k$-cycle is $(-1)^{k-1}$. If you want more details: $(a_1...a_k)=(a_1 a_2) (a_2 a_3)...(a_{k-1} a_k)$, which is a product of $k-1$ permutations, each of them having signature $-1$.

2) yes, i am sure. Apply your morphism $f$ to the relations $\rho^5=1,$ and so on...

Comment: Ok, I don't know about it because I didn't have permutation signature. However I still don't understand something here: I know the claim that permutation is even when $\text{sgn}(\rho)=1$ where $\text{sgn}(\rho)=(-1)^r$ and $r$ is a number of transposition in permutation. For a 3 nad 4-cycle I have 0 translation, so $\text{sgn}(\rho)=-1$. Why does this not come out of my claim?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "0 translation", or what could be a translation  in this setting. A 4-cycle is a product of 3 transpositions, so it has sign −1, I don't think there's more to say.